# Bot Framework PromptDialog not asking first prompt

Tags: c#, botframework

I am learning the Microsoft Bot Framework, so I'm going through tutorials and working on some sample dialogs. I was trying to write a calculator bot. (The bot asks for an integer, an operation, and another integer).

But, I cannot get the bot to actually ask the user for their input. And if the user types anything after initiating the dialog, the response is `$invalid need: expected Call, have Poll`. I saw some issues saying that you can't use a prompt and `context.Wait` in the same function call, but I haven't found anything saying how to handle this.

```
public class CalculatorDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    protected readonly String[] operators = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
    private long Left { get; set; }
    private long Right {get; set; }
    private String Operator { get; set; }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(Calculate);
    }

    private async Task Calculate(IDialogContext context, 
                                 IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        await result;

        PromptDialog.Number(
            context,
            async (ctx, lhs) => { Left = await lhs; },
            "Left hand side"
        );

        PromptDialog.Choice<string>(
            context,
            async (ctx, op) => { Operator = await op; },
            new PromptOptions<string>("Operator:", options: operators)
        );

        PromptDialog.Number(
            context,
            async (ctx, rhs) => { Right = await rhs; },
            "Right hand side"
        );

        long res;
        switch (Operator) { /* res = Left Operator Right */}

        await context.PostAsync($"The result is: ${res}");
    }
}
```

The code that calls this is

```
switch (activity.Text)
{
    case "math":
        context.Call(new CalculatorDialog(), this.ResumeAfterSubDialog);
        break;
}
```

Where `ResumeAferSubDialog` continues the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I find that you continuously call `PromptDialog.Number` and `PromptDialog.Choice` method, you can modify your code to execute/call next ***PromptDialog*** in previous ***Resume*** handler, the following code snippet is for your reference.

```
private async Task Calculate(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    await result;

    PromptDialog.Number(
        context,
        LeftReceivedAsync,
        "Left hand side"
    );
}

private async Task LeftReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<long> lhs)
{
    Left = await lhs;

    PromptDialog.Choice<string>(
        context,
        OperatorReceivedAsync,
        new PromptOptions<string>("Operator:", options: operators)
    );
}

private async Task OperatorReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> op)
{
    Operator = await op;

    PromptDialog.Number(
        context,
        RightReceivedAsync,
        "Right hand side"
    );
}

private async Task RightReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<long> rhs)
{
    Right = await rhs;

    long res;

    //switch (Operator) { /* res = Left Operator Right */}

    await context.PostAsync($"The result is: ${res}");

}
```

***Note:***

Based on my test, the `PromptDialog.Choice` does not work fine with these special characters (*`"+", "-", "*", "/"`*), it does not recognize selected option as avilable option, but let user retry it again.

*Test pic1:*

[image]

If possible, you could provide a different list of options, for example:

```
protected readonly String[] operators = { "add (+)", "subtract (-)", "multiply (*)", "divide (/)" };
```

*Test pic2:*

[image]

Comment: Ok, so can there only every be one `PromptDialog` call per method?

Comment: `can there only every be one PromptDialog call per method?` Hi @EdwardMinnix, do you mean that creating a instance of **PromptDialog** and then call **.Number()** and **.Choice()** methods via that instance object? If you check the definition of PromptDialog class, you can find the **.Number()** and **.Choice()** methods are defined as ***static***, which would be invoked without the need for creating an instance of a class.

Comment: what I meant was I wanted to know that if one of the mistakes in my code was using **.Number()** and **.Choice()** in a chained fashion (all in the same method) rather than having a method chain like you have up there.

Comment: As far as I know, calling both PromptDialog.Number() and  PromptDialog.Choice() methods one by one at a time in same method is not recommended, and as you mentioned in your question, which might cause exception.